# Why doesn't fastboot work over wireless ADB?

Tags: android, fastboot

It's simple enough to connect to ADB wirelessly. Basically something like this:

Get the device ID for the specific device you're connected to:

```
adb devices
```

Then:

```
adb -s <device id> tcpip 5555
```

Then get the IP for that device:

```
adb -s <devid id> shell ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

And finally, make the connection:

```
adb connect <ip>:5555
```

Then I can disconnect the cable and run ADB commands on the device wirelessly.

However, fastboot fails. And

```
fastboot devices
```

Returns nothing.

Is there a way around this, or does fastboot always require a wired connection?

Comment: I don't imagine device in fastboot mode has network drivers initialized

Comment: `fastboot` is a bootloader so should take as minimal amount of space/resources as required to do its job (flashing ROM, factory reset) and not a full OS. I expect it to always be wired and not worry about supporting all of the various versions of WiFi(b/g/n/ac/6)